# doing maths with php array based on excel function

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I am new to PHP and stackoverflow and try to figure things out for myself before asking but I am having a little trouble doing some maths on an array I have pulled from a database with PHP.

So far I have an array of numbers called $array['sn']

I have created a function in excel that does the maths and works well in excel but I cant figure out a way to do it in PHP.
the excel function is `=QUOTIENT(E32,65536)&QUOTIENT(E32-F34*65536,256)&(G33-G35*256)`

`E32` being the value I start with i.e $sn

`F34` being the answer to the first quotient

`G35` being the answer to the second quotient

`G33` being `E32-F34*65536`

I want to take a number e.g. 3675177 divide it by 65536 but without the remainder which is 56, then multiply 56 by 65536 which equals 3670016, then find the difference between 3670016 and 3675177 which is 5161. Then divide 5161 by 256 with no remainder which is 20 then multiply 20 by 256 and subtract 5161 which is 41.

The end result from 3675177 should be 562041. I want to do this calculation on every number in the $array['sn'], any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The PHP equivalent of Excel's QUOTIENT(10,3) function is: `intval(10/3); // this will equal 3`. Here's the intval doc page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation and formatting of the output would be like this:

```
$n = 3675177;

$const  = 65536;
$const2 = 256;

$a = intval($n / $const);   // intval returns only the integer part of a number
$x = $n % $const;           // $n % $const means "the remainder of $n  / $const"
$b = intval($x / $const2);
$c = $x % $const2;    

// Two options to handle values of $c < 10:
// if ($c < 10) $c = "0$c";
// $c = str_pad($c, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo "$a$b$c";
```

I would recommend using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply the calculation to your array of values.

Comment: The above works well for me thanks. I have a slight problem though, if the last calculation is lower than 10 i.e if $n was 3498498 i would end up with 53982 where I actualy need 539802. how would I go about this? could I use an if statement with a string pad?

Comment: @adamp Yes, I think that should work well. I updated the answer to show a couple of options.

Comment: what would be the best way to reverse this code? so I start with 562041 and the result of echo "$a$b$c"; would be 3675177?.

Answer (score 0):

There are php arithmetic operations you can use.

I would do something like this:

```
$initialNumber = //the initial number, wherever you get it from
$entireDivision = ceil($initialNumber/65536)-1;
$remainder = $initialNumber%65536;
$remainderMultiplied = $remainder * 56;
$difference = $initialNumber - $remainderMultiplied;
$differenceDivided = ceil($difference/256)-1;
$differenceMultipliedAndSubstracted = ($differenceDivided * 256) - $difference;
```

Maybe I used too many variables, this is to be a bit more easy to understand for you. Maybe I did some operation wrong, check it out too. But this is the idea of mathematic operations in php. Maybe you should put this inside a [php function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp) with parameters, so your code gets cleaner if you use multiple times.

EDIT: You should put this code inside a function, then run a `foreach` loop in your array running this function taking as parameter the value of the array position.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();

foreach ($array['sn'] as $key => $a) {
    $b = intval($a / 65536);
    $c = ($a - $b * 65536);
    $d = intval($c / 256);
    $e = $c - $d * 256;

    $results[$key] = $b . $d . $e;
}

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Well, intval has already been described to him and he said he created the function in Excel himself, so he should understand the code...